# How to avoid audio clicks when automating the bypass paremeter in the tremolo plug-in in Logic?

Tags: software, logic-pro

Re: http://memecode.com/temp/JmacMiraclesGtrs.m4a

The bass has a tremolo on it in verse 1, and for the accents I remove the effect using automation to bypass the tremolo. However that causes little clicks in the audio. I even went so far as to put the bypass automation nodes on zero crossings in the audio. Still clicks.

Maybe I should be automating the depth instead?

Or am I doing it wrong some other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switching between `bypass`and `on` can produce a click in many plugins and there is no way to avoid it. In these cases you don't want to automate the `bypass`.

You have other options. The more obvious is to automate the `depth`. Keep it at `0` when you don't want the effect, and increase it on the parts where you want the effect.

Another popular option is to use two tracks (two audio tracks or one audio track feeding an aux track through a bus), one with the effect and one without it. You switch among them using `gain` and/or `mute` automation and/or audio edits. This requires more work but gives you extra flexibility, as you can very easily treat the wet and dry portions separately. Effects can dramatically change a sound, so you might want the wet part to be louder/softer, or equalized differently, with different delay/reverb/compressor, or whatever. This would be very tedious and time consuming using only one track for both dry and wet.

If you think you are doing perfectly fine with the tremolo changes, use one track and automate the depth. If you think the wet part might need some adjustments to fit in the idea and mix, use one extra track for the wet portion.

Answer (score 1):

If you can reach a zero-effect point with your depth parameter, then yes: my advice would be to automate your depth instead.

I'm not a Logic user so I don't know if automation is as user-friendly as in other softs, but this approach may allow you to reduce your tremolo level in a more progressive way than just pushing a bypass button. A hard automation slope will have the same effect, and it will most likely solve your clic issue.

Besides, if later in your track you want to make your tremolo softly fade in/out, you'll be able to do that in the same automation track. All in one.

You might find further information here : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2378228

Hope this helps!